# Clojure: How to use Mapping with an Anonymous Function?

Tags: function, clojure

```
 (defn recurse

   [temp total]                    ;total is: (and true true(and false))

  (map (fn [i]
     (cond
      (seq? i) (println "");If total is not a single parenthesis (single sequence), recur until it is

      (= i 'and)  (System/exit 0)  ;I want this to be called only when the **second** "and" is called

      :else (println "This should never print I think")
       ))
   idealreturn)
)
```

I want (System/exit 0) to be called **only** when the second "and" is detected in *total* and not before. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with mapping a function over the data to transform it. There are a couple of ways to get what you are looking for:

1. Don't use map, and use reduce instead. Reduce is for building up state over time. So you could reduce it into an expression, and each time you encounter an `and`, you look to see if there is already an `and` in the result you are building up, and if that `and` is already there, call the exit.
2. Have the function you are mapping over the input do only one thing, convert single items into more meaningful things. Then once it is done, pass that result to a second function that checks if it's time to exit.

Giving each thing one responsibility makes for code that's much easier to write, and composing them afterwords is efficient and easy. It's also much easier on you later when you come back to work on the code later.

Comment: 1. Does not work because there could be more than just "and." That was just for simplicity. Regarding 2. I do have a function that check if there is only one sequence and manipulates that last thing: (cond
  (not-any? seq? total) (finalevaluation temp)
  )  .......... However, it still "Calls" the "and" line twice